# PLZ HELP MEH IMPROVA MEH LOLCAT CODEZ, WHUCH CALCULUTS FAWCTORIALS

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, lolcode

SUNCE MEH BEEN WRUTEN CODEZ IN MUNY DIFFRNT PROGRAMMING LANGUAGES, MEH THOUGHTZ THAT ME TRY TO WRITE CODEZ IN AN ESOTERIC LANGUAGE. MEH CODEZ CALCULUTS A FAWCTORIAL OF UH USR INPUTTED NUMBAH IN [LOLCODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE), LOL.

SOME OF MEH QUSTIONS:

- IZ MEH CODEZS A IDMITIC LOLCAT PROGUM?
- IZ THERE A GOODER WAY OF WRUTING MEH `factorial` FUNCSHUNS?

---

**TRANSLATION:**

---

Since I've been writing and trying programs in many different languages, I thought I'd give esoteric language a crack. So I used [LOLCODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE) to write a program that calculates the  factorial of a user given number:

Questions for consideration:

- Is my LOLCODE code idiomatic to the LOLCODE language?
- Is there a easier way to write my `factorial` function?

### LOLCAT.lol

```
BTW Calculates the factorial for a user given integer

BTW Author: Pythonic
BTW Version: 1.0


HAI 1.2
HOW DUZ I factorial YR n
    BOTH SAEM n AN 0, O RLY?
        YA RLY
            FOUND YR 1
        NO WAI
            FOUND YR PRODUKT OF n AN factorial DIFF OF n AN 1
    OIC
IF U SAY SO

HOW DUZ I main
    I HAS A user_input

    VISIBLE "ENTER AN NUMBAH"
    VISIBLE "TO FINDZ ITZ FAWCTORIAL:: "

    GIMMEH user_input

    VISIBLE "DE FAWCTORIAL OF " user_input " IZ:: " factorial user_input
    VISIBLE "KTHXBYE!"
IF U SAY SO

main
KTHXBYE
```

For those of you who are not fortunate enough to have a LOLCODE compiler, here is a link to a [REPL.IT](https://repl.it/languages/lolcode) of the code.

<sub>**NOTE: All answer must be given in proper LOLCODE English, with an optional translation in regular English. Failure to do so will result in me releasing my LOLCATS upon you....**</sub>

Comment: user_input in lolcode ??? YU_TOLD?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your factorial function enters an infinite loop if passed a negative integer. Since the entire program seems to take 1 input and then exit, I think it would be best if the program gave an error message and then exited.